# How to delay start multiple carousel in the same page?

Tags: javascript, carousel, bootstrap-5

I've a page with multiple bootstrap 5.3 carousels and I'm trying to start them delayed.
The first carousel should start after 1 second, the second one after 2 second, the 3rd after 3 and so on.

Each carousel has its unique `id`, like:

```php
<div class="card-image">
    <div id="carousel__<?php echo $row['guid']; ?>" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <a href="<?php echo $galleryLink; ?>">
                    <img class="img-card-gallery" src="<?php print $coverPhoto . '?t=' . time(); ?>" alt="">
                </a>
            </div>
            <?php
for ($i = 0; $i < count($imgfileNames); $i++) {
    echo ' 
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <a href="' . $galleryLink . '">
                <img class="img-card-gallery" src="' . $imgfileNames[$i] . '?t=' . time() . '" alt="' . $imgartTitles[$i] . '">
            </a>
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <!-- Here you can add Caption -->
            </div>
        </div>
        ';
}
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- <a href="<?php echo $galleryLink; ?>"><span class="<?php if($galleryTitle=='') echo 'card-title-without-text'; else echo 'card-title-with-text'; ?>"><?php echo $galleryTitle ?></span></a>-->
</div>
```

And this is my JavaScript which doesn't work, instead all carousels start at the same time.

```html
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var carousels = $('.carousel-fade');
        var initialInterval = 1000; 

        carousels.each(function(index, carousel) {
            var carouselInstance = new bootstrap.Carousel(carousel, { interval: 0 }); 
            console.log('Impostazione del carosello numero ' + index + ' con intervallo ' + initialInterval + 'ms');
            setTimeout(function() {
                carouselInstance.interval = initialInterval; 
                carouselInstance.cycle(); 
            }, 1000); 
            initialInterval += 1000; 
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: The `interval` property controls how many milliseconds to wait before the carousel goes to the next slide. What you want is to change the `setTimeout` wait time from 1000 to `(index + 1) * 1000`.

Answer (score 1):

Changes made to your code:

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var carousels = $('.carousel-fade');
        var initialInterval = 1000;

        carousels.each(function(index, carousel) {
            var carouselInstance = new bootstrap.Carousel(carousel, { interval: 0 });
            console.log('Setting up carousel number ' + index + ' with an interval of ' + initialInterval + 'ms');
            setTimeout(function() {
                carouselInstance.interval  = initialInterval; // Use interval to change the interval
                carouselInstance.cycle();
            }, initialInterval); // Delay the start of each carousel
            initialInterval += 1000;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Use carouselInstance.interval to change the interval of the carousel, as interval is the internal property that controls the carousel's timing.

Change the setTimeout delay to initialInterval milliseconds so that each carousel starts after the desired delay.

I hope your problem is solved. Thank you.